# Calling a method that was assigned to a variable in a pre update hook

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I'm trying to create a helper function for all my pre update hooks:

```
const preUpdateHelper = function(updateQuery, updateMethod) {
  const update = updateQuery.getUpdate();
  if (update && update.$set && update.$set.emailAddress) {
    const emailAddress = update.$set.emailAddress;
    updateMethod({}, {$set: {emailAddress: emailAddress.trim()}});
  }
  updateMethod({},{ $set: { updatedAt: new Date() } });
}
UserSchema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', function() {
  const updateMethod = this.findOneAndUpdate;
  var x = function() {
    console.log('hi');
  };
  console.log(x)
  x();
  console.log(updateMethod);
  updateMethod({},{$set: {updatedAt: new Date()}});
  console.log('after update method ')
  preUpdateHelper(this, this.findOneAndUpdate);
});
```

The logs print:

```
[Function: x]
hi
[Function]
```

So, `after update method` is not printed. I'm getting the error: `Cannot set property 'op' of undefined`.

I can't figure out why I can't call this method after assigning it to a variable. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, `this` context.

```
const updateMethod = this.findOneAndUpdate;
//...
updateMethod(args);
```

isn't the same as

```
this.findOneAndUpdate(args);
```

Try binding the method:

```
const updateMethod = this.findOneAndUpdate.bind(this);
```

Here's the minimal example demonstrating how those things are different:

```js
const foo = {
  myName: "foo",
  introduceYourself: function() {
    console.log("Hello, my name is " + this.myName);
  }
}

foo.introduceYourself(); // logs what everyone expects

const introduceYourself = foo.introduceYourself;

introduceYourself(); // logs undefined

const introduceFoo = introduceYourself.bind(foo);

introduceFoo(); // logs foo again
```

`introduceYourself` isn't exactly what in OOP is called a *method*. It's not really tied to `foo`. Only by invoking it as an object property: `foo.introduceYourself` (or equivalent: `foo['introduceYourself']`), you're passing it `foo` as its `this` context. `Otherwise,`introduceYourself` doesn't get it.

Other ways to pass `this` context to a function are `bind` (shown here), `call` and `apply`.

Further reading - Kyle Simpson's "You Don't Know JS: this & Object Prototypes".

Comment: Why isn't it the same? And why does the second way work? Can you explain more / attach links to documentation?

Comment: It does work, so marking it as accepted. Still would like to know what is going on under the hood here if anyone has any information on that :)

Comment: Added some more.